# Can and should AppHostOnly be changed for IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, compression

A post by a Microsoft supporter on [this Microsoft website](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161580.aspx) states that you can't override `noCompressionForHttp10` in the `web.config` file.

Can the httpCompression section be changed from "AppHostOnly" to "Everywhere" so that you could do this? Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the `noCompressionForHttp10` parameter will not take effect on individual locations, and that is (as it sounds) a bug, changing the section's configuration scope with `allowDefinition` won't help you. You might just end up breaking something.

Choose, server-wide, between true or false